# How do you generate Boundary In PHP?

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data, boundary

I'm using Curl library to simulate "multipart-form-data" submission, then I noticed that I need to generate a unique string, but I have no idea how to do that.

For example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;  
boundary=---------------------------491299511942
Content-Length: 95418
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="b"
/page.asp
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="c"
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="d"
true
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e"
1
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"
```

How to generate that boundary? From library or just some hack?

**EDIT**: in this example Boundary=491299511942

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you using curl you don't need prepare data "manually"

```
$post_data = array(
    'a' => '@/absolute/path/to/file',
    'b' => '@/absolute/path/to/file',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: Hmm , but what about Boundary?

Comment: I'm using LiveHttpHeaders and i have seen data sent like the above example...normally i need to prepare data like this ?

Comment: Curl will properly generate a multipart/form-data request if given '@filename' POST data. You don't need to generate them manually. If you do not need to transfer a file, then you don't need multipart/form-data to begin with.

Comment: This is such an important answer: the curl api sets the headers for you.  Just make sure your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is a single dimensional array and that you have no raw byte fields in the post packet.  Alternatives for the "@" prefix is `CURLFile` object.

Comment: Not working for me(((
Tried and fopen($path, 'r')

Answer (score 3):

To answer the actual question, you can do something like this:

```
$boundary = hash('sha256', uniqid('', true));
```